# Tools to do data processing from Java

Tags: java, sql, hadoop, bigdata, data-processing

I've got a legacy system that uses SAS to ingest raw data from the database, cleanse and consolidate it, and then score the outputted documents.

I'm wanting to move to a Java or similar object oriented solution, so I can implement unit testing, and otherwise general better code control. (I'm not talking about overhauling the whole system, but injecting java where I can).

In terms of data size, we're talking about around 1 TB of data being both ingested and created. In terms of scaling, this might increase by a factor of around 10, but isn't likely to increase on massive scale like a worldwide web project might.

The question is - what tools would be most appropriate for this kind of project?

Where would I find this information - what search terms should be used?

Is doing processing on an SQL database (creating and dropping tables, adding columns, as needed) an appropriate, or awful, solution?

I've had a quick look at Hadoop - but due to the small scale of this project, would Hadoop be an unnecessary complication?

Are there any Java packages that do similar functionality as SAS or SQL in terms of merging, joining, sorting, grouping datasets, as well as modifying data?

Comment: can you please elaborate on -what is the system all about? -is it just a report generation system from month old logs?(here am stressing on "availability of output data") do you need it quickly? -what type of data is being consumed by the system? use of real-time/stream processing? How well is the existing system distributed?  Will it be possible for you to distribute the data over a cluster?

Comment: Hi, thanks. 
It's a weekly assessment of new records. It's not time critical as it runs over the weekend.
Currently runs on a single multi-core processor, at this stage clustering doesn't look feasible.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard for me to prescribe exactly what you need given your problem statement.

It sounds like a good database API (i.e. [native JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) might be all you need with a good open source database backend)

**However**, I think you should take some time to check out [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/features.html).  It's a fantastic tool and may meet your scoring needs very well.  Taking a search engine indexing approach to your problem may be fruitful.

Comment: I think the question is - is it appropriate to use a database for this kind of processing? (As opposed to simple data storage and retrieval).

Answer (score 1):

I think the question you need to ask yourself is

1. what's the nature of your data set, how often it will be updated.
2. what's the workload you will have on this 1TB or more data in the future. Will there be mainly offline read and analysis operations? Or there will also have a lot random write operations?

Here is an [article](http://www.thoughtworks.com/pt/insights/blog/hadoop-or-not-hadoop) talking about if to choose using Hadoop or not which I think is worth reading.

Hadoop is a better choice if you only have daily or weekly update of your data set. And the major operations on the data is read-only operations, along with further data analysis. For the merging, joining, sorting, grouping datasets operation you mentioned, [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/) is a Java library running on top of Hadoop which supports this operation well.